# Grails app won't run, but receiving no errors

Tags: java, spring, grails, intellij-idea, groovy

I'm new to grails and am trying to compile and run an app from the source code that a vendor provided to us. I'm doing this in IntelliJ, but am just trying to run it within the terminal. I was able to compile the app successfully at the command line. Now when I try grails run-app, it runs through a series of outputs, and then stops at:

> Configuring Spring Security Core ... 
>   ... finished configuring Spring Security Core

And then it stops and the prompt returns. Here's the entire output:

> C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app>grails
>   run-app --verbose --stacktrace Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:
>   -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed
>   in 8.0 Base Directory:
>   C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app
>   | Packaging Grails application        extraSrcDirs =
>   C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app/src/installer/groovy
>   extraSrcDirs =
>   C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app/src/installer/i18n
>   extraSrcDirs =
>   C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app/src/installer/spring
>        [copy] Warning: C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app\src\installer\groovy
>   does not exist.
>        [copy] Warning: C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app\src\installer\i18n
>   does not exist.
>        [copy] Warning: C:\Users\xxx.xxx\Documents\Repositories\xe_repo\banner_student_ssb_app\src\installer\spring
>   does not exist. | Compiling 2 source files          | Compiling 2
>   source files      | Compiling 2 source files..... configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy
>   configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy
>   configuration: classpath:WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class 2016-11-10
>   16:37:38,714 [main] INFO  configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils 
>   - Using configuration file '$HOME/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy' 2016-11-10 16:37:38,716 [main] INFO 
>   configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using configuration
>   file '$HOME/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy' 2016-11-10
>   16:37:38,719 [main] INFO  configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils 
>   - Using configuration file WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class from the classpath (e.g., from within the war file) configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy
>   configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy
>   configuration: classpath:WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class | Running
>   Grails application 2016-11-10 16:37:47,779 [localhost-startStop-1]
>   INFO  configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using
>   configuration file '$HOME/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy'
>   2016-11-10 16:37:47,782 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using configuration
>   file '$HOME/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy' 2016-11-10
>   16:37:47,790 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using configuration
>   file WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class from the classpath (e.g., from
>   within the war file) configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy
>   configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy
>   configuration: classpath:WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class 2016-11-10
>   16:37:54,007 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using configuration
>   file '$HOME/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy' 2016-11-10
>   16:37:54,008 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using configuration
>   file '$HOME/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy' 2016-11-10
>   16:37:54,010 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO 
>   configuration.ApplicationConfigurationUtils  - Using configuration
>   file WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class from the classpath (e.g., from
>   within the war file) configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/banner_configuration.groovy
>   configuration:
>   file:C:\Users\xxx.xxx/.grails/StudentSSB_configuration.groovy
>   configuration: classpath:WebAppExtensibilityConfig.class
>
> Configuring Spring Security Core ... ... finished configuring Spring
>   Security Core

I've tried running it as "grails run-app --verbose --stacktrace" and I get the same exact thing.

How am I supposed to troubleshoot if there are no errors? (I'm also new to IntelliJ, and Spring, btw). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - It was in target/stracktrace.log and target/logs/xxxxxxxxxx.log. This was define in an app configuration .groovy file.